# Warning on Custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm creating popup custom UIView. I had created custom.xib, custom.swift. In my custom.xib, my owner's object refer to custom. I had implement init func in custom.swift and loadNib with the name "custom". I got infinity call from the init func until I got this warning and breakpoint at the `super.init(coder: aDecoder)`.

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information. This will
>   significantly reduce the quality of type information available.

**ViewController**

```
let customView: Custom = Custom(frame: CGRectMake(100,100,200,200))
self.view.addSubview(customView)
```

**Custom**

```
var view: Custom!
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    loadNib()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    loadNib()
}

private func loadNib() -> Custom {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Custom", owner:  self, options: nil)[0] as! Custom
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `loadNib()` method is useless in this case. It returns instance of `Custom` view, but the result is never used by `init` methods. You can declare your `loadNib()` as a class method and remove `init` in `Custom` class:

```
class Custom: UIView {
    class func loadNib() -> Custom {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Custom", owner:  self, options: nil)[0] as! Custom
    }
}
```

Then you can use your `loadNib()` method to instantiate `Custom` view directly in `ViewController` and change frame in this way:

```
let customView = Custom.loadNib()
customView.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,200,200)
self.view.addSubview(customView)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because your `loadNib()` and `init` methods are causing a recursion. imnosov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33593136/3050006) should solve your problem.